# list comprehension and map without lambda on long string

Tags: python, python-3.x, built-in

```
$ python -m timeit -s'tes = "987kkv45kk321"*100' 'a = [list(i) for i in tes.split("kk")]'
10000 loops, best of 3: 79.4 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s'tes = "987kkv45kk321"*100' 'b = list(map(list, tes.split("kk")))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 66.9 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s'tes = "987kkv45kk321"*10' 'a = [list(i) for i in tes.split("kk")]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.34 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s'tes = "987kkv45kk321"*10' 'b = list(map(list, tes.split("kk")))'
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.38 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s'tes = "987kkv45kk321"' 'a = [list(i) for i in tes.split("kk")]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.51 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s'tes = "987kkv45kk321"' 'b = list(map(list, tes.split("kk")))'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 usec per loop
```

I tried using timeit and wonder why creating list of lists from string.split() with list comprehension is faster for a shorter string but slower for longer string.

Comment: I guess that searching through a long list for the split simply increases the overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fixed setup costs for `map` are higher than the setup costs for the listcomp solution. But the per-item costs for `map` are lower. So for short inputs, `map` is paying more in fixed setup costs than it saves on the per item costs (because there are so few items). When the number of items increases, the fixed setup costs for `map` don't change, but the savings per item is being reaped for more items, so `map` slowly pulls ahead.

Things that `map` saves on:

1. Only looks up `list` once (the listcomp has to look it up in the builtin namespace every single loop, after checking the nested and global scopes first, because it can't guarantee `list` isn't overridden from loop to loop)
2. Executes no Python bytecode per item (because the mapping function is also C level), so the interpreter doesn't get involved at all, reducing the amount of hot C level code

`map` loses on the actual call to `map` (C built-in functions are fast to run, but comparatively slow to call, especially if they take variable length arguments), and the creation and cleanup of the `map` object (the listcomp closure is compiled up front). But as I noted above, neither of these is tied to the size of the inputs, so you make up for it rapidly if the mapping function is a C builtin.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of timing is basically useless.

The time frames you are getting are in microseconds - and you are just creating  tens of different one-character-long-elements list in each interaction. You get basically linear type, because the number of objects you create is proportional to your string lengths. There is hardly any surprise in this.

Comment: Ah! Alright, I understand the linear thing.
Thanks, btw